AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username' in Flask application
This is my API Endpoint of an Update Route for a particular URL in Flask:
# Update Route for a particular trip
@app.route('/trips/<int:trip_id>', methods=['PUT'])
def update_trip(trip_id):
    trip = trips.get(trip_id) #query from the database
    data = request.get_json()
    
    trip.username = data['username']
    trip.start_at = datetime.strptime(data['start_at'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    trip.from_gps = data['from_gps']
    trip.end_at = datetime.strptime(data['end_at'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    trip.distance = data['distance']

    return jsonify({'message': 'Trip updated successfully!'})

and the error I get in the console when running the Code in PostMan is:

File "E:\Wlink\Location_Tra\backend\main.py", line 608, in update_trip
trip.username = data['username']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

The filename is main.py in flask.
The Screenshots:
Postman

I am sending Raw JSON in PUT request.

try passing force=True to request.get_json() see https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Request.get_json.html

Can you share the headers you're sending too?

I have set the Content-Type to: application/json in headers section

You need to set the request content type to application/json
This is needed for request.get_json as mentioned on the doc
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json
You can force to ignore this check with request.get_json(force=True)
You can additionally debug using is_json
